# Unable to connect to SQL Server Express 2014 when signed in with local account

Tags: c#, sql, express, entity-framework-6, connection

Installed SQL Server Express 2014 & can connect/query with SSMS. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (C#) and EF 6 to programatically connect to the server. In all the following scenarios I'm using the same connection string + am using the "sa" account with the correct password in the connection string.

When I sign in to the computer with a Windows domain account (ex: domain\username) then run the code it works fine.

When I sign in to the computer using a local account (ex: computername\username) account then run the code it fails with the following error: **The underlying provider failed on Open**. Note that I can launch and use SSMS w/out  problems.

Here's my connection string.

```
metadata=res://*/[efName].csdl|res://*/[efName].ssdl|res://*/[efName].msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\'Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=db-name;Integrated Security=True;User ID=sa;Password=[psw];MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;User Instance=False\'
```

I've tried with Integrated Security on or off (same result). Tried Data Source as ".\SQLExpress" or "[machineName]\SQLExpress" (same result).

After digging a bit I found the following entry in the Windows Event Viewer.

- Level: Information
- Source: MSQL$SQLEXPRESS
- Task Category: Logon
- Message: Login failed for user 'computername\username'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'db-name'. [CLIENT: ]

Looks to me like SQL Server windows service is using some kind of network auth prior to allowing a connection to SQL Server.

Comment: What type of authentication does your sql server allow? Mixed Authentication? Only username+password?

Comment: Installed with Mixed. Using sa account as credential in the connection string.

Comment: post your `ConnectionString` as well

Comment: How do you log into SSMS? Can you use your windows creds? Have you added permissions to that windows user on BOTH the server and database levels?

Comment: I can sign into SSMS with Windows auth (my account), or SQL Server Auth (using the sa credential mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably no surprise that the error message returned by EF/SQL didn't help at all. It has nothing to do with the underlying provider...

After some trial/error I've whittled it down to this. It's required that you set **IntegratedSecurity=false** when providing specific userName/Password credentials in the connection string. That's it.